# Hot Proxy in Shopware 6 doesn't reload the page/ CSS or JS changes

Tags: javascript, symfony, webpack, proxy, shopware

When I start the Hot-Proxy Server in Shopware 6 with: **./psh.phar storefront:hot-proxy** I get the following error and nor the CSS or JS changes are injected into the browser.

```
    Starting the hot reload server: 
    
    Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update`
    ℹ Compiling Shopware 6 Storefront
    ✔ Shopware 6 Storefront: Compiled with some errors in 5.40s
     ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors2:14:09 PM
    
    These relative modules were not found:
    
    * ../../../bundles/MyTheme/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--8-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--8-3!/Users/lukas/Sites/MyTheme/var/theme-entry.scss
    ############
    Storefront proxy server started at http://localhost/MyTheme/public:9998
    ############
```